# Need to design a CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm creating checkboxes dynamically in Android and they're getting like this:

[image]

and I want:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd use a separate label for the text in a relative layout, where you can easily align these by specifying alignParentTop|alignParentLeft and rightOf

Comment: please post the code

Comment: You can settext for checkbox and set gravity as top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use gravity property to achieve what you need

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lorem"
    android:gravity="top"/>
```

Comment: CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb.setText("\t" + Select.rs.getString("fldTexto") + "\n");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
          new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        cb.setLayoutParams(params); 

cb.setGravity(Gravity.TOP); 

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add **dynamically** also by putting the TextView and the CheckBox into a layout
then add the layout to your parent layout.
Assuming you have a parent layout by the name **parentLayout** you can:

```
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(context);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("what ever you want...");
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP); //Aligning the text itself inside the textview to the left (for LTR language)

    // LinearLayout Container
    LinearLayout ll_container = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll_container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    ll_container.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP); //Aligning the textview and the checkbox  to the left inside the ll_container
    ll_container.addView(cb);
    ll_container.addView(tv);


    parentLayout.addView(ll_container);
    parentLayout.refreshDrawableState();
```

Comment: Of course you can add more attributes to the TextView or CheckBox as to any view e.g. setTextColor(Color.GREEN) and so on.